# Email draft - add recipients -Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

**running the following**

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application

$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)



$mail.to.add("a@b.com")

$mail.Subject = "subject"

$mail.Body = "body"


$mail.save()
```

**receiving:**

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

```
    At line:x char:x
+   $mail.to.add("a@b.com")
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqAN9.png
```

Comment: I also tried $null = $mail.to.add("a@b.com")  as well as [Void]$mail.to.add("a@b.com")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The To property of $mail seems to be a string so you should assign the recipient to it directly:

`$mail.to = "a@b.com"`

There is also the `Recipients` property which can be used to add multiple recipients.